# Can I pass a string from a activity to another one but still get it update when the original updated?

Tags: firebase, kotlin, android-intent, bundle

I get score from firebase in GameActivity and then pass it to ScoreActivity using bundle
I want to update score in my app realtime when database changed, how can I achieve it?

Thank you.

Comment: Instead of passing things through different activities, I would just stick to one activity and multiple fragments. With this, you can create an activityviewmodel and then observe the desired string from the database

Comment: thank for your answer, I already build my app with many activities :(  
I don't know if I connect to database each time activity showed it would slowdown my app?

Comment: To understand better, the score that you get in the GameActivity is constantly changing and you want to get real-time updates about the score in ScoreActivity? Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo yes, that's what I want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this comment:

> The score that you get in the GameActivity is constantly changing and you want to get real-time updates about the score in ScoreActivity?

To get real-time updates about a property that is constantly changing, you need to attach a real-time listener in the second activity as well.

According to the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#read_data):

> To read data at a path and listen for changes, use the addValueEventListener() method to add a [ValueEventListener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/ValueEventListener) to a [DatabaseReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot).

Simply passing an object through an Intent or Bundle doesn't provide this real-time feature.

Since you didn't select a tag for a particular database, I'll also show you how to achieve this in the case of Cloud Firestore, where to listen for [real-time updates](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen) you should use addSnapshotListener() on [DocumentReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentReference) or on a [CollectionReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/CollectionReference) object.

So don't be afraid to use multiple listeners, all queries are pipelined over a single connection.

Comment: I checked your FireApp and still don't know how to implement auto update data in UI when database change. Can you help me with that?

Comment: The FireApp doesn't get the data in real-time. However, when using either addValueEventListener() in the case of the Realtime Database or addSnapshotListener() in the case of Cloud Firestore, you'll get the desired behavior.